# uialertview not opening as the top window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

I'm opening an `UIAlertView` which works fine on the iPhone, but when running on iPad 3.2, the alert doesn't come to the top:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" ...];
[alert show];
```

It's as though it's hidden beneath whatever `UIView` is currently at the top. If you've encountered this before or can suggest a solution (window ordering, visibility, moving view placements, etc) that would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you provide the code where you are creating and showing the `UIAlertView` you may get better responses.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for adding the code, but you should show the full code (just place dummy values if there is a privacy concern) since the above obviously won't compile. Please also indicate when you call this alertview (in a button click event, view loading, etc.).

Comment: i would but it's too complex and at the core of it is that the window ordering needs to be adjusted somehow. but i think we have a solution. just found the setWindowLevel which will probably do what i need it to by making the alert view high enough.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm not sure how initializing an `UIAlertView` could be too complex for this site, but I'm glad to hear you have a potential solution. Since you've already asked the question (and there will probably be others with the same question in the future), would you mind posting your solution as an answer?

Comment: It does seem a bit weird. You weren't doing it on a secondary thread by any chance?

Comment: lxt - nah it was that one view had a window level higher than the default window level for the alert view. once the alert view was higher it was good to go.